# Sorry 7 split rule

Tags: sorry

In Sorry, when using the 7 split card, am I allowed to split the 7 to bump an opponents pawn to home and finish the count with another pawn of mine. It doesn't really specify in rules of the 7 split but I am allowed to bump opponent if I land on their spot in bump rules. Please clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Sorry can I split a 7 move card to a single pawn and move it only 2?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34708/in-sorry-can-i-split-a-7-move-card-to-a-single-pawn-and-move-it-only-2)

Comment: Not a duplicate... the linked question is answered by pointing out that there is no legal move that adds up to 7 in that situation, which is not the case here. The answer here may be the opposite of the other question, but even if it’s the same, it’s for a different reason.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can split the seven between two pawns. If one of the pawns ends on a space occupied by another player's pawn, that other pawn is sent back to Start (not Home).

The only restrictions noted for the split are that you must use all of the 7, and you cannot start your own pawn.

> 7 - Moves one pawn forward 7 spaces or can split the forward move
>   between any two pawns. Using this card to start a pawn is against the
>   Sorry rules. The instructions do state that you can part of the 7 to
>   get a pawn Home but that you must be able to use the balance of the
>   move for another pawn.

http://www.boardgamecapital.com/sorry-rules.htm

If you mean "split" the seven into two moves with a single pawn, then no. That's not splitting the seven. (again by the quoted rules)